# I can't filter many values with `subset` in DataFrames in Julia using `in` directly

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

Wondering why can't use "in" when using "subset". "filter" could use it.

```
using DataFrames

df=DataFrame( a=["cat","dog","tiger","parrot","cat","parrot"],
             r=[2,5,1,3,6,3])

subset(df, :a => a->a in["cat", "parrot"], :r => r->r.>1) ##get an error

#but

subset(df, :a => ByRow(a->a in ["cat", "parrot"]), :r => r->r.>1) 

#or

filter([:a,:r]=>(a,r) -> a in ["cat", "parrot"] &&  r.>1, df)

#Thanks.
```

Comment: You need elementwise comparison : `in.(:a, Ref(["cat", "parrot"])` (the `Ref` is a way to tell Julia not to briadcast over its content).

Comment: This is the key difference between `filter` (which works on rows` and `subset` (which works on whole columns). If they both worked the same one of them would not be needed. In some cases it is more convenient to use one and in other to use the other.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple answer using `InMemoryDatasets` package

```
using InMemoryDatasets

ds=Dataset(df)

filter(ds, [:a, :r], by=[in(["cat", "parrot"]), >(1)])
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation reads:

```
help?> subset
... All transformations must produce vectors containing true or false.
```

Hence you can do

```
julia> subset(df, :a => a -> in.(a, Ref(["cat", "parrot"])), :r => r -> r .> 1 )
```

or

```
julia> subset(df, [:a, :r] => (a,r) -> (in.(a, Ref(["cat", "parrot"]))) .& (r .> 1) )
```

Note that if the list is long you might want to wrap `["cat", "parrot"]` to a set.

Comment: I've been testing and it is nice the improvement in time when you don't use anonymous functions but a function that evaluates the field like ` :r => >(1)` but haven't found a way to use this structure with many columns. your opinion?. thanks.

Comment: doesn't `subset(df, [:a, :r] =>  ...` use many columns? I am not sure what your question is

Comment: yes, the next part will be something like (a, r) -> (a.=="dog") .& (r.>1)... as. you describe before but in that situation we are using an anonymous function "(a,b)->" and that takes more allocation and time I guess. What about an unique function that evaluates both column and get the filtering, or  a way to combine these functions ==() , :>() so we got something like  subset(df, [:a, :r] => function or combined function. Hoping myself is clear.